# error: Google Maps API is required - even when API was registered

Tags: javascript, console, maps

I have this site [here](https://cosasabrosa.netlify.com/) that I built for a client but the Google Maps API is not working correctly. If you go to the site, click the contact us link in the `nav` bar. You will see the map not showing, then if you just reload the page two or three times the map will show.

I copied and pasted the exact link from Google into my HTML file, with the API key that they gave me. I also borrowed a file called `gmaps.js`, which you can search for on Google, and implemented the map in my `javascript` file with the following code:

```
  /* MAPS */
    new GMaps({
    div: '.map',
    lat: 42.2803784,
    lng: -83.7301047
  });
```

The github repo is public and can be viewed here:

https://github.com/seanrobenalt/cosasabrosa

The problem doesn't seem to be too complicated but I can't figure it out. Hoping somebody is willing to take a look...